# How to tell whether an existing site is using WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl, code-analysis

I'm trying to work out whether a certain website is using WebGL. I'm comfortable using Chrome's developer tools, but I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for. I see various variables and classes with "webgl" in the name, but no call to `initWebGL()` for instance.

Is there a reliable, perhaps simpler, way to tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been awhile since the original question but thought I would share:
If you use the "Profile" tab in Chrome Dev Tools, and record a second or two you should see in the results a row with the name "GPU". If there is a `<canvas/>` in the DOM, but it's not using WebGL, the GPU row won't be there.

**With WebGL**

[image]

**Without WebGL**

[image]

Comment: Awesome. You might want to embed those images directly in your answer.

Comment: This answer is false. Profile [this](http://greggman.github.io/doodles/emoji-draw.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60730128/128511). Both use 2D canvas not WebGL and the GPU shows up. [This page](https://greggman.com/downloads/examples/intersecting-elements-3d-css.html) doesn't even use canvases at all and the GPU shows up.

Comment: gman is correct. I went back and reproduced the experiment I did before to get the screen shots and in both cases (with and without WebGL) the GPU line was present. I'm assuming a chrome update changed this.

Comment: I see GPU row at http://example.com/. No any canvas there.

Answer (score 3):

First, there should be a `<canvas>` element in the body. If not, it can't be WebGL.

Second, open the chrome debugger and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for MacOS). At the very bottom, expand the search pane if necessary. Search for "bindBuffer". You absolutely must bind buffers to do anything with WebGL. It will be used.

Answer (score 1):

In **Google Chrome** Version 97 this worked for me:

1. Open the "Elements" tab in Chrome DevTools
2. Select the `<canvas>` in the DOM which you want to inspect, so it shows `== $0` next to it (see screenshot below)
3. Open the "Console" tab in Chrome DevTools
4. Enter `$0.getContext('2d')`, when it shows `null` then it's a WebGL-powered canvas, when it shows `CanvasRenderingContext2D` then it's a plain 2D canvas

**Here are some sites to try:**

WebGL Canvas - https://get.webgl.org/

Non-WebGL Canvas - http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/canvas-nebula.htm

**Screenshot:**

[image: WebGL Canvas]