# Balls bouncing off of each other

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on this script where I have x-number bouncing balls (in this case 20 balls) in a canvas. 
My question is, how do I make them bounce off each other when they hit, as well as bounce off the yellow rectangle when they hit it?

```
var mycanvas =document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx=mycanvas.getContext("2d");
var w=500,h=500;

mycanvas.height=h;
mycanvas.width=w;

var ball=[];

function Ball(x,y,r,c,vx,vy){
  this.x=x; //starting x coordinate
  this.y=y; //starting x coordinate
  this.r=r; //radius  
  this.c=c; //color 
  this.vx=vx; // x direction speed
  this.vy=vy; // y direction speed
  this.update=function(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        //changing direction on hitting wall
        if(this.y>=(w-10)||this.y<=10){
        this.vy=-this.vy;
         }
        if(this.x>=(h-10)||this.x<=10){
        this.vx=-this.vx;
         }
}
}

function clearCanvas(){
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
}

var count;
for (count = 0; count < 20; count++) {
  var rndColor=Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1); //random color
    ball[count]= new Ball(Math.floor((Math.random() * 490) + 1),Math.floor((Math.random() * 490)+1),5,'red',5,5);
}

function update(){
  var i;
  clearCanvas();
    //draw rectangle 
    ctx.rect(250, 200, 10, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fill();

  for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        ball[i].update();
    }
}

setInterval(update, 1000/60);
```

Comment: By modeling velocity transfer based on angle of collision (for circles, that's nice and easy), with dampening if you want a stabilizing scene. Also, instead of a function, write a `Ball` class so that you can house your logic in a more organized fashion - if you're already a graphics pro, no need to, but if you're still taking your first steps, the added verbosity and organisation  far outweighs "performance efficiency".

Answer (score 4):

There are several methods you can use. The following methods are about the simplest.

### Update

I have added an example that uses the second method. See snippet at the bottom.

### Defining the balls

Each example is as an object called `Ball`.

```
// x,y position of center, 
// vx,vy is velocity, 
// r is radius defaults 45, 
// m is mass defaults to the volume of the sphere of radius r
function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r = 45, m = (4 / 3 * Math.PI * (r ** 3)) {
    this.r = r;
    this.m = m;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
}
Ball.prototype = {
    // add collision functions here
};
```

The code assumes the balls are touching.

### Elastic collisions

The logic used can be found at [wikis elastic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional) page

The calculation splits the forces into two parts for each ball. (4 in total for 2 balls)

1. The transfer of energy along the line between the balls,
2. The adjustment of energy per ball along the tangent of the collision point

### Equal mass

Each ball has the same mass which means that the transfer of energy is balanced and can be ignored

After the function is called each ball has a new velocity vector.

Note that if you call collision and the velocities mean that the balls are moving away from each other (collision paradox) then the result will have the balls moving into each other (resolution paradox)

To keep the math simple the vector magnitudes `u1`, `u2`, `u3`, and `u4` are converted into a unit that is the length of the line between the ball centers (square root of `d`)

```
collide(b) {  // b is the ball that the collision is with
    const a = this;
    const x = a.x - b.x;
    const y = a.y - b.y;  
    const d = x * x + y * y;

    const u1 = (a.vx * x + a.vy * y) / d;  // From this to b
    const u2 = (x * a.vy - y * a.vx) / d;  // Adjust self along tangent
    const u3 = (b.vx * x + b.vy * y) / d;  // From b to this
    const u4 = (x * b.vy - y * b.vx) / d;  // Adjust b  along tangent

    // set new velocities
    b.vx = x * u1 - y * u4;
    b.vy = y * u1 + x * u4;
    a.vx = x * u3 - y * u2;
    a.vy = y * u3 + x * u2;     
},
```

### Different masses

Each ball has its own mass and thus the transfer needs to calculate the amount of energy related to the mass that is transferred.

Only the energy transferred along the line between the balls is effect by the mass differences

```
collideMass(b) {
    const a = this;
    const m1 = a.m;
    const m2 = b.m;        
    const x = a.x - b.x;
    const y = a.y - b.y;
    const d = x * x + y * y;

    const u1 = (a.vx * x + a.vy * y) / d; 
    const u2 = (x * a.vy - y * a.vx) / d;  
    const u3 = (b.vx * x + b.vy * y) / d;    
    const u4 = (x * b.vy - y * b.vx) / d; 

    const mm = m1 + m2;
    const vu3 = (m1 - m2) / mm * u1 + (2 * m2) / mm * u3;
    const vu1 = (m2 - m1) / mm * u3 + (2 * m1) / mm * u1;

    b.vx = x * vu1 - y * u4;
    b.vy = y * vu1 + x * u4;
    a.vx = x * vu3 - y * u2;
    a.vy = y * vu3 + x * u2;     
},
```

### Example

Simple ball collision example. Balls bound by lines (Note lines have an outside and inside, if looking from the start to the end the inside is on the right)

Collisions are fully resolved in chronological order between frames. The time used is a frame where 0 is the previous frame and 1 is the current frame.

```js
canvas.width = innerWidth -20;
canvas.height = innerHeight -20;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const GRAVITY = 0;
const WALL_LOSS = 1;
const BALL_COUNT = 20;  // approx as will not add ball if space can not be found
const MIN_BALL_SIZE = 13;
const MAX_BALL_SIZE = 20;
const VEL_MIN = 1;
const VEL_MAX = 5; 
const MAX_RESOLUTION_CYCLES = 100;
Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
Math.rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
Math.randI = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min | 0; // only for positive numbers 32bit signed int
Math.randItem = arr => arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0]; // only for arrays with length < 2 ** 31 - 1
// contact points of two circles radius r1, r2 moving along two lines (a,e)-(b,f) and (c,g)-(d,h) [where (,) is coord (x,y)]
Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime = (a, e, b, f, c, g, d, h, r1, r2) => { // args (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, r1, r2)
    const A = a * a, B = b * b, C = c * c, D = d * d;
    const E = e * e, F = f * f, G = g * g, H = h * h;
    var R = (r1 + r2) ** 2;
    const AA = A + B + C + F + G + H + D + E + b * c + c * b + f * g + g * f + 2 * (a * d - a * b - a * c - b * d - c * d - e * f + e * h - e * g - f * h - g * h);
    const BB = 2 * (-A + a * b + 2 * a * c - a * d - c * b - C + c * d - E + e * f + 2 * e * g - e * h - g * f - G + g * h);
    const CC = A - 2 * a * c + C + E - 2 * e * g + G - R;
    return Math.quadRoots(AA, BB, CC);
}   
Math.quadRoots = (a, b, c) => { // find roots for quadratic
    if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-6) { return b != 0 ? [-c / b] : []  }
    b /= a;
    var d = b * b - 4 * (c / a);
    if (d > 0) {
        d = d ** 0.5;
        return  [0.5 * (-b + d), 0.5 * (-b - d)]
    }
    return d === 0 ? [0.5 * -b] : [];
}
Math.interceptLineBallTime = (x, y, vx, vy, x1, y1, x2, y2,  r) => {
    const xx = x2 - x1;
    const yy = y2 - y1;
    const d = vx * yy - vy * xx;
    if (d > 0) {  // only if moving towards the line
        const dd = r / (xx * xx + yy * yy) ** 0.5;
        const nx = xx * dd;
        const ny = yy * dd;
        return (xx * (y - (y1 + nx)) - yy * (x -(x1 - ny))) / d;
    }
}
const balls = [];
const lines = [];
function Line(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
}
Line.prototype = {
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
    },
    reverse() {
        const x = this.x1;
        const y = this.y1;
        this.x1 = this.x2;
        this.y1 = this.y2;
        this.x2 = x;
        this.y2 = y;
        return this;
    }
}
    
function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r = 45, m = 4 / 3 * Math.PI * (r ** 3)) {
    this.r = r;
    this.m = m
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
}
Ball.prototype = {
    update() {
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        this.vy += GRAVITY;
    },
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.r, this.y);
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.TAU);
    },
    interceptLineTime(l, time) {
        const u = Math.interceptLineBallTime(this.x, this.y, this.vx, this.vy, l.x1, l.y1, l.x2, l.y2,  this.r);
        if(u >= time && u <= 1) {
            return u;
        }
    },
    checkBallBallTime(t, minTime) {
        return t > minTime && t <= 1;
    },
    interceptBallTime(b, time) {
        const x = this.x - b.x;
        const y = this.y - b.y;
        const d = (x * x + y * y) ** 0.5;
        if(d > this.r + b.r) {
            const times = Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime(
                this.x, this.y, 
                this.x + this.vx, this.y + this.vy, 
                b.x, b.y,
                b.x + b.vx, b.y + b.vy, 
                this.r, b.r
            );
            if(times.length) {
                if(times.length === 1) {
                    if(this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) { return times[0] }
                    return;
                }
                if(times[0] <= times[1]) {
                    if(this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) { return times[0] }
                    if(this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) { return times[1] }
                    return
                }
                if(this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) { return times[1] }                
                if(this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) { return times[0] }
            }
        }
    },
    collideLine(l, time) {
        const x1 = l.x2 - l.x1;
        const y1 = l.y2 - l.y1;
        const d = (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1) ** 0.5;
        const nx = x1 / d;
        const ny = y1 / d;            
        const u = (this.vx  * nx + this.vy  * ny) * 2;
        this.x += this.vx * time;   
        this.y += this.vy * time;   
        this.vx = (nx * u - this.vx) * WALL_LOSS;
        this.vy = (ny * u - this.vy) * WALL_LOSS;
        this.x -= this.vx * time;
        this.y -= this.vy * time;
    },
    collide(b, time) {
        const a = this;
        const m1 = a.m;
        const m2 = b.m;
        const x = a.x - b.x
        const y = a.y - b.y  
        const d = (x * x + y * y);
        const u1 = (a.vx * x + a.vy * y) / d
        const u2 = (x * a.vy - y * a.vx ) / d
        const u3 = (b.vx * x + b.vy * y) / d
        const u4 = (x * b.vy - y * b.vx ) / d
        const mm = m1 + m2;
        const vu3 = (m1 - m2) / mm * u1 + (2 * m2) / mm * u3;
        const vu1 = (m2 - m1) / mm * u3 + (2 * m1) / mm * u1;
        a.x = a.x + a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y + a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x + b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y + b.vy * time;
        b.vx = x * vu1 - y * u4;
        b.vy = y * vu1 + x * u4;
        a.vx = x * vu3 - y * u2;
        a.vy = y * vu3 + x * u2;
        a.x = a.x - a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y - a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x - b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y - b.vy * time;
    },
    doesOverlap(ball) {
        const x = this.x - ball.x;
        const y = this.y - ball.y;
        return  (this.r + ball.r) > ((x * x + y * y) ** 0.5);  
    }       
}

function canAdd(ball) {
    for(const b of balls) {
        if (ball.doesOverlap(b)) { return false }
    }
    return true;
}
function create(bCount) {
    lines.push(new Line(-10, 10, ctx.canvas.width + 10, 5));
    lines.push((new Line(-10, ctx.canvas.height - 2, ctx.canvas.width + 10, ctx.canvas.height - 10)).reverse());
    lines.push((new Line(10, -10, 4, ctx.canvas.height + 10)).reverse());
    lines.push(new Line(ctx.canvas.width - 3, -10, ctx.canvas.width - 10, ctx.canvas.height + 10)); 
    while (bCount--) {
        let tries = 100;
        debugger
        while (tries--) {
            const dir = Math.rand(0, Math.TAU);
            const vel = Math.rand(VEL_MIN, VEL_MAX);
            const ball = new Ball(
                Math.rand(MAX_BALL_SIZE + 10, canvas.width - MAX_BALL_SIZE - 10), 
                Math.rand(MAX_BALL_SIZE + 10, canvas.height - MAX_BALL_SIZE - 10),
                Math.cos(dir) * vel,
                Math.sin(dir) * vel,
                Math.rand(MIN_BALL_SIZE, MAX_BALL_SIZE),
            );
            if (canAdd(ball)) {
                balls.push(ball);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
function resolveCollisions() {
    var minTime = 0, minObj, minBall, resolving = true, idx = 0, idx1, after = 0, e = 0;
    while(resolving && e++ < MAX_RESOLUTION_CYCLES) { // too main ball may create very lone resolution cycle. e limits this
        resolving = false;
        minObj = undefined;
        minBall = undefined;
        minTime = 1;
        idx = 0;
        for(const b of balls) {
            idx1 = idx + 1;
            while(idx1 < balls.length) {
                const b1 = balls[idx1++];
                const time = b.interceptBallTime(b1, after);
                if(time !== undefined) {
                    if(time <= minTime) {
                        minTime = time;
                        minObj = b1;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(const l of lines) {
                const time = b.interceptLineTime(l, after);
                if(time !== undefined) {
                    if(time <= minTime) {
                        minTime = time;
                        minObj = l;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            idx ++;
        }
        if(resolving) {
            if (minObj instanceof Ball) {
                minBall.collide(minObj, minTime);
            } else {
                minBall.collideLine(minObj, minTime);
            }
            after = minTime;
        }
    }
}
create(BALL_COUNT);
mainLoop();
function mainLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    resolveCollisions();
    for(const b of balls) { b.update() }
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(const b of balls) { b.draw() }
    for(const l of lines) { l.draw() }
    ctx.stroke();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I was looking for. However, I can't make it work, can you give an example of where it should be inserted in my script? I am a novice in this field. ;-)

Comment: @BRR The functions are used when two balls collide. Because there is a time step between frames you must resolve the collisions in chronological order. Before updating all balls, Point "A" Find and calculate time for all collisions since last frame. If there is/are collisions, find the earliest collision, apply the function, projecting balls back along new velocities to start of last frame, repeat from "A" finding collision at time greater equal to just resolve collision time and until there are no more collisions. Then update all balls.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the example. :-)
Many useful parameters to customize the script.

I have two questions:
1: I have inserted a line segment, but the balls behave as if the line is going through the entire screen. How do I do so the balls can go both below and above the line segment?

```lines.push (new Line (400, 200, 400, 400));
lines.push ((new Line (400, 200, 400, 400)). reverse ());```

2: How can I style the balls? If I would like, for example, 10 balls that are blue and have a size of 20 as well as 40 red ones that have a size 10?

Answer (score 2):

To bounce balls off of one another, he's what you need to know

1. Have the balls collided? The way to determine is to measure the distance between the centers of the two circles. If this is less than the combined radiuses, the balls have collided
2. What direction should they have after colliding? Use use atan2 to calculate the angle between the centers of the two balls. Then set them in opposite directions on that angle, in a way that they don't end up deeper within each other. Of course, this simple solution ignores existing momentum that the balls may have. But doing the momentum calculation (which involves mass, speed, and current angle) is more complicated.